# Capture the JSON data? Postman data is getting printed in the console

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs

I have a Dto class :- Company.java

```
public class Company {

    private String companyId;
    private String companyName;

    Company(){
    }

    public String getCompanyId() {
        return companyId;
    }
    public void setCompanyId(String companyId) {
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }
    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }
    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }   
}
```

Then I have a serviceInterface.java

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json",
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
@Path("/demoJson")
public Response demoJson(Company company);
```

ServiceImpl.java

```
public Response demoJson(Company company) {
    String result = "Company created : " + company;
    return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();
}
```

Json Data Sent through Postman :-

```
{
   "comapanyId":"123";
   "companyName":"Google";
}
```

Json Data Sent through postman is getting printed in the console.I have added the Jackson dependency as well...What am I missing here... I am a novice so for any silly mistakes.

Comment: Why does it matter if the eclipse log prints it? Have you considered that there is some logging mechanism that prints out data sent to each request?

Comment: @ cricket_007 how do i capture the json data in the arguments....i want to parse the json data further and use it.

Comment: It's not clear at which part of you program is getting JSON data. Or how `demoJson(Company company)` is converting the JSON data into a Company object.

Comment: @ cricket_007  I am sending a POST request to the following url through json :- http://localhost:8080/GenericApp/rest/genericAppServices/demoJson ......I have added the Jackson depedency which will marshal and unmarshal....and i have'nt added any binding annotations in the DTO class as JAX-RS has a prewritten content handler that can convert Java Beans to and from JSON.....please correct me if m wrong...

Comment: @RohitGoswami AFAIK returning Response.status(201) does not return any data. So you might want to remove Produces annotation. Besides this, I don't see any issue with the code.

Comment: Okay, so Jackson is deserializing your objects for you. You can either make it not do that, so you get JSON strings, or you could use Jackson to convert the object back. Realistically, though, I don't see the need to access the JSON data.

Comment: @ cricket_007  @sudhirshakya i am getting confused about where the json data goes...where does it get stored ....?.... ideally when i send parameters through postman in x-www-form-urlencoded i get the data in the ServiceImpl .....But in this case when I put a degub point in the ServiceImpl class my program dosent reach there.... simply the json is getting printed in the console....how do i capture the json data.....

Comment: @RohitGoswami Did you explore logging options provided by Postman?and on do u want data over to a stream or particular console

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal I have already logged the data .... i just saw my logs i get json data in the payload... i want to access the json data sent through postman in my serviceimpl class....

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal i want to get the json data from the arguments in the serviceimpl class...

Comment: First, make sure you're sending your data as "application/json" and not as xml or urlencoded. Second, you might want to define your endpoints in a Resource-style class instead of an interface and see if that works. You can find a couple examples here https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-tomcat/